# Want to add a role when reacting to a message discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to have someone get a role when they react to a message. I'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level you would want to listen to the messageReactionAdd event and then after parsing the reaction, add whoever who reacted to a user role with addMemberToRole()

Event:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd

Add member:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole

Comment: I'm pretty sure messageReactionAdd only works for cached messages, so if the bot restarts, it will only work for the messages sent after the bot was online

Comment: Thanks for the update, looks like that version of discord.js is deprecated. Link updated